# group memberships in (AD) ldap Realm

Tags: active-directory, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, realm

I use the JAAS Framework for the authentification and authorization process in a java ee enterprise application. I use GlassFish as the application server. My realm configuration looks like:

```
<auth-realm name="ads-realm" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm">
  <property name="jaas-context" value="ldapRealm" />
  <property name="base-dn" value="CN=Users,DC=company,DC=intern" />
  <property name="directory" value="ldap://ad.company.intern:389" />
  <property name="search-filter" value="(&amp;(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))" />
  <property name="search-bind-password" value="****" />
  <property name="search-bind-dn" value="ldapSvc@company.intern" />
</auth-realm>
```

This configuration works fine in my environment. See following log entries:

```
FEIN: JAAS login complete. 
FEIN: JAAS authentication committed.
FEIN: Password login succeeded for xyz
```

but i don't receive a LDAP Group membership(s) from my Active Directory

```
FEIN: LDAP: Group memberships found: 
FEIN: LDAP: login succeeded for: xyz
```

Which configuration/entry/mapping have I to do, to receive a group membership from AD?

Surely, I can add the property

```
<property name="assign-groups" value="Users" />
```

to my GlassFish configuration, but that is not exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this extra property:

`group-search-filter` Search filter to find group memberships for the user. The default value is uniquemember=%d (%d expands to the user element DN). In the case of Active Directory this should be member=%d